# to INSERT the location path of the uploaded picture to the user's pic_location

Tags: php, sql

**How do I INSERT the location path of the uploaded picture to the user's pic_location in the database?**

So I managed to upload the picture via php to a folder BUT my problem now is that and I don't know how the query will look if I want to achieve that...

**The member is logged in when he uploads the pic so the SESSION is running.**

I will give you my code to have a look see and if you can spot what to do...

Thanks

**My picUpload.php** (Where I uploaded the picture and where I want to INSERT the location path into the user's pic_loaction column in the table users)

```
    <?php
         include 'connect.php';
         include 'header.php';

         if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in'] == true)
        {
             //This is the directory where images will be saved 
             $target=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/avatars/" . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

             //This gets all the other information from the form 
             $pic_location=($_FILES['file']['name']); 

             //Writes the information to the database
             $sql = "UPDATE users SET pic_location='$target' WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION['user_id'];

             //Writes the photo to the server 
             if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
             { 

             //Tells you if its all ok 
             echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
             } 
             else { 

             //Gives and error if its not 
             echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
             }

        }
        else
        {
            //nothing
        }
?>
```

**my connect.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    //connect.php

    $server = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'mydatabase';

    if(!mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''))
    {
        exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
    }
    if(!mysql_select_db($database))
    {
        exit('Error: could not select the database');
    }
?>
```

**my header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <title> ShareLink </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

        <script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        <!-- Back to Top easing jQuery -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="css/ui.totop.css" />

        <!-- jquery --> 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- easing plugin ( optional ) -->
        <script src="js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- UItoTop plugin -->
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                /*
                var defaults = {
                    containerID: 'moccaUItoTop', // fading element id
                    containerHoverClass: 'moccaUIhover', // fading element hover class
                    scrollSpeed: 1200,
                    easingType: 'linear' 
                };
                */

                $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> ShareLink </h1>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
            <a class="item" href="/index.php">Home</a> -
            <a class="item" href="/create_topic.php">Create a topic</a> -
            <a class="item" href="/create_cat.php">Create a category</a> - 
            <a class="item" href="/members.php"> Members </a> - 
            <a class="item" href="/search_form.php"> Search </a> - 
            <a class="item" href="/profile.php"> Profile </a>


            <div id="userbar">
            <?php
            if($_SESSION['signed_in'])
            {
                echo 'Hello <b>' . htmlentities($_SESSION['user_name']) . '</b>. <a class="item" href="signout.php">Log out</a>';
            }
            else
            {
                print'<a class="item" href="signin.php">Log in</a> or <a class="item" href="signup.php">Register</a>';
            }
            ?></div>
        </div>
            <div id="content">
```

**and here is my users table in my database.sql file**

```
CREATE TABLE users (  
user_id     INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
user_name   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
user_pass   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
user_email  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
user_date   DATETIME NOT NULL,  
user_level  INT(8) NOT NULL,  
pic_location  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
UNIQUE INDEX user_name_unique (user_name),  
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)  
);
```

Comment: you need to save the $target, that's where the picture is now located. "UPDATE users SET pic_location='".mysql_real_escape_string($target)."' WHERE user_id=".intval($userid)

Comment: See my updated file! I used the code you gave me that makes sense but I get an error saying: Undefined variable: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\picUpload.php on line 12... How do one fix that because I can't see whats wrong there?

Comment: because $user_id is not defined. you said the user is logged in at this point - this is where you need to put the value of the user id

Comment: somewhere in the beginning of the code (in header.php or connect.php) you are checking if the user is logged in. you need to fetch the user info from the database. this info contains the user_id of the user, and later on when you run the UPDATE query, you add the user_id to the WHERE part

Comment: OK. I updated the question... AGAIN... Thanks for your patience so far! I'm new to sql and it's quite of a challenge for me! Must I like use a SELECT query to select the user's ID when he is logged in? But in which one, connect.php or header.php?

Comment: heh that really depends on you. what connect.php and header.php are for? where do you check that the user is logged in? it's how you choose to implement your system

Comment: well yeah I sort of changed my stuff... It uploads awesomely BUT my database table still does not change any bit at all... Take a look at what I did...

Comment: i'd recommend adding the user_id to the session (if user_name is unique then you can use it instead). the unique value that you decide on - goes in the where clause

Comment: haha, i solved it! will put up the code now or just answer later on... Thanks for your help galchen! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

store the variable `$target` as pic_location and the query is not insert it should be update query.

Answer (score 1):

As punit wrote, use the variable $target to update the record of the user. In the query, use an UPDATE instead of an INSERT, make sure you define the ID of the user (the INSERT that you have right now simply adds a new row, but you want to modify an existing row, so you need a WHERE clause) and you should definitely sanitize $target before using it in the query, otherwise you have a blind SQL injection.